# Use Task.FromResult for creating async action

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Please consider this action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task RemoveUserFromGroups(string connectionId, List<string> groupNames, string pusherAddress)
{
    var onlineUser = OnlineUser.Instance;
    await OnlineBusiness.RemoveUserFromGroups(onlineUser.Id, onlineUser.CustomerId, onlineUser.IsTrader, connectionId, groupNames, pusherAddress);
}
```

and this method:

```
public static Task<bool> RemoveUserFromGroups(int userId, int customerId, bool isTrader, string connectionId, List<string> groupNames, string pusherAddress)
{
    return Task.FromResult(PusherBusiness.RemoveUserFromGroups(userId, customerId, isTrader, connectionId, groupNames, pusherAddress));
}
```

The `PusherBusiness` class in a third party library that in the class call a web service.
I want to change my controller to async mode.is this correct to use Task.FromResult and return Task and then await on it?
Is this async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This isn't asynchronous at all.

This will run synchronously, create a task, await that completed task (which completes synchronously) and move on using the same thread.

For this to be asynchronous you need some actually asynchronous operation in there. For example if `RemoveUserFromGroups` calls a web service it should do so asynchronously and offer `RemoveUserFromGroupsAsync` or at least `Begin`/`EndRemoveUserFromGroups`.

As long is doesn't offer that overload there's not much you can do to actually have an asynchronous operation.

Comment: @ShahroozJafari all your code does is use a dependency. As long as that dependency doesn't support async there's not much you can do.

Comment: You could put it to a background job if it is worth doing this (Task.Run). Not ideal however.